# What is the evidence for laryngeal in *méh₂tēr?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, proto-indo-european, vocabulary

Wikitionary shows a PIE word [**méh₂tēr*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aProto-Indo-European/m%C3%A9h%E2%82%82t%C4%93r) but I never seen this word spelled with a laryngeal. There was a long vowel there but how is it correct to analyze it to be **-eh₂-* rather than just **ā*?

Comment: I don't remember that much about PIE, but isn't it (sometimes?) assumed that PIE had no /a/-like vowels, and that hence all later a's are due to vocalization of nasals, laryngeals, and whatnot?

Comment: @Cerberus I never heard this theory. There are roots with -a- along with roots with -e-, although there are relatively few of them.

Comment: It seems that Cerberus is trying to describe the Laryngeal Theory.

Comment: Quite a few IEists hold the theory Cerberus mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending upon the specific view that one accepts concerning the development of the accent systems of Baltic and Slavic, the Baltic cognate would compel a reconstruction with *h2.

Lithuanian (nom.) *móteris* [the acute diacritic here indicates the surface word accent] ‘woman’ belongs to the third accent class, which indicates that the stem *moteri-* contained a so-called "acute" intonation (the use of the terms "acute" and "circumflex" in Baltic and Slavic accentology is fraught and convoluted -- beware). If one follows the position of Kortlandt (though also more or less sustained in Petit's recent *Untersuchungen zu den baltischen Sprachen*) that only IE laryngeals or voiced stops in syllable codas could eventually produce "acute" intonation, then the reconstruction *meh2-ter- would be necessary.

Furthermore, insofar as one does analyze the word into a root and suffix -ter, *no* IE root whatsoever that participates in derivation lacks a consonant following the root's full-grade (*confer* the roots in the *Lexicon der Indogermanischen Verben*). IE grammatical elements that lack final consonants consist exclusively of particles (e.g., *su 'good, well'), prepositions (e.g., *pro ‘before’), and pronouns.  Thus, IE constraints on licit root structures would exclude *mā- as a root. So even setting the Baltic considerations aside, *meh2-ter remains a preferable reconstruction.